# How to implement Google Auth in phonegap?

Tags: api, cordova, authentication

I have to implement log-in to my app in phonegap using Google login.Is there any api to do this or tutorial to guide?

Answer (score 6):

There is a good example on this link;
http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html
i hope it helps