# How to login with Google OAuth2 using Angularjs inside Phonegap using ClientID and ClientSecret

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, google-oauth

I am trying to login from my Phonegap App using Angularjs (using the Ionic Framework) through Google OAuth2. Currently I am using the http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html for logging in. But it is creating really ugly looking code and quite a hard to understand code when I am using Angular-UI-Router for Ionic.

This issue seems to be spiralling around without any proper answers. I hope it should be solved now. The Google Angular Guys should help. 
[How to implement Google Auth in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205845/how-to-implement-google-auth-in-phonegap)

The closest topic is [How to use Google Login API with Cordova/Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930744/how-to-use-google-login-api-with-cordova-phonegap), but this is not a solution for angularjs.

I had to transfer the javascript variable values using the following code:

```
        var el = document.getElementById('test');
        var scopeTest = angular.element(el).scope();
        scopeTest.$apply(function(){ 
            scopeTest.user = user;
            scopeTest.logged_in = true;
            scopeTest.name = user.name;
            scopeTest.email = user.email;
        });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did the solution like this, where TestCtrl is the Controller where the Login Button resides. There is a mix of jquery based $.ajax calls, which I am going to change to the angualar way. The google_call function basically calls the google_api which is mentioned in the link mentioned above in phonegap-tips.

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup) {
$scope.logged_in = false;
$scope.getMember = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
};
$scope.test = function(){
    $ionicPopup.alert({"title":"Clicked"});
}

$scope.call_google = function(){
    googleapi.authorize({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',

    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }).done(function(data) {
        accessToken=data.access_token;
        // alert(accessToken);
        // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
        console.log(data.access_token);
        //$ionicPopup.alert({"title":JSON.stringify(data)});
        $scope.getDataProfile();
    });
};
$scope.getDataProfile = function(){
    var term=null;
    //  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
    $.ajax({
           url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token='+accessToken,
           type:'GET',
           data:term,
           dataType:'json',
           error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
           },
           success:function(data)
           {
           var item;

           console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
           // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
           window.localStorage.gmailLogin="true";
           window.localStorage.gmailID=data.id;
           window.localStorage.gmailEmail=data.email;
           window.localStorage.gmailFirstName=data.given_name;
           window.localStorage.gmailLastName=data.family_name;
           window.localStorage.gmailProfilePicture=data.picture;
           window.localStorage.gmailGender=data.gender;
           window.localStorage.gmailName=data.name;
           $scope.email = data.email;
           $scope.name = data.name;
           }
        });
        //$scope.disconnectUser(); //This call can be done later.
};
$scope.disconnectUser = function() {
  var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token='+accessToken;

  // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: revokeUrl,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(nullResponse) {
      // Do something now that user is disconnected
      // The response is always undefined.
      accessToken=null;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
      console.log("-----signed out..!!----"+accessToken);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      // Handle the error
      // console.log(e);
      // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
      // https://plus.google.com/apps
    }
  });
};
})
```

I am providing this answer for the newbies who faced similar problems like mine while trying to login using Google OAuth2. So asking for Upvotes shamelessly as I am new here too!

Comment: As a fellow noob inquiring, was there a reason to why you used the jQuery ajax call over Angular's $http,get(...) ?

Comment: Actually this can be very much replaced with $http.get(....) with a success function and an error function. I also did not know that when I did it! Thanks for the mention.