# Unable to obtain Google OAUTH access_token using Javascript embedded in an application

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

Title:  Unable to obtain Google OATH access_token using Javascript embedded in an application.

I have been struggling to obtain the Google OATH access_token value in JavaScript for several days now. Eventually I want to use it for Google Analytics but for now I hope to just login to my Google account. I saw in the following post code which is very close to what I hope to use:
[How to login with Google OAuth2 using Angularjs inside Phonegap using ClientID and ClientSecret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140840/how-to-login-with-google-oauth2-using-angularjs-inside-phonegap-using-clientid-a)

My implementation of this example runs without error but it fails to obtain the access token. Can anybody show which adjustment is needed to obtain the access_token value?  This is my JavaScript:

```
// Module declaration.
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var googleapi = {
    authorize: function(options) {
        console.log(options); // **** THIS WORKS.
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferred.reject({ error: 'Not Implemented' });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
};

// Controller.
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello";
    $scope.call_google = function(){
        console.log("inside call_google"); // **** THIS WORKS.
        googleapi.authorize({
            client_id: '108adf6o7nn.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            client_secret: 'mySecret',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        }).done(function(data) { // **** THIS BLOCK IS NEVER ENTERED EVEN WHEN client_id is empty.
            accessToken=data.access_token;
            console.log(data.access_token);
        });
    };
}]);
```

This is my HTML. I realize using JQuery and AngularJS together is bloat and this is fine for now. My main concern is being able to obtain the access_token in JavaScript.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Starting Angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- Identify the controller and model to be used. -->
    <div ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="call_google()">
        <h1 ng-bind="greeting"></h1>
        <br />
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your assistance and insight.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js

Comment: Also, this is an alternative which is also useful: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I really appreciate it.  These are valid approaches for web applications but mine is not a web application.  With oauth there are a series of requests and responses that must be handled. I still want to use JavaScript from a variety of clients and I believe this approach would work if I could obtain the access_token value. I am running the example on a local server but plan to embed this from a series of clients on different platforms which are not using web servers.

Comment: PS. Dave thank you for the edit!